# Как обновить данные input radio?

Tags: input, php

Всем привет!

Не могу найти инфу по такому вопросу:

Нашёл следующий приём для передачи выбора типа доставки (пока получилось передавать цифру только в таблицу заказа):

```
    <input type="radio" name="nameRadio" value="300" checked> Наш курьер (Стоимость доставки 300 руб)
    <input type="radio" name="nameRadio" value="0">Самовывоз

    <script>
window.onclick = function onclickRadio() {
  var nameRadio = document.getElementsByName('nameRadio');
  for (var i = 0; i < nameRadio.length; i++) {
    if (nameRadio[i].type === 'radio' && nameRadio[i].checked) {
        rezultatRadio = nameRadio[i].value;       
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('rezultatRadio').innerHTML = rezultatRadio;
}
</script>
```

Здесь выводится выбранный тип доставки с указанной суммой.

```
<td align="center"><output id="rezultatRadio">300</output> руб</td>
```

А вот что и как можно и нужно применить, чтобы выбранную цифру можно было приплюсовывать к общей сумме заказа (вместо знаков вопроса):

```
<p class="total" align="center">Общая сумма заказа: <span class="product-price"><?=number_format($_SESSION['total_price'],2) +  **??????** ;?> руб</span></p>
```

Заранее благодарен за информацию. :)

Answer (score 1):

Заведи переменную с `totalprice` типа

```
window.onload = function(){
 totalPrice = "<?=$_SESSION['total_price']?>";
}
```

, а в `onclick` добавь

```
document.getElementById('product-price').innerHTML = rezultatRadio + totalPrice;
```

, но... интересен момент, откуда ты берешь тоталпрайс при отправке формы на оплату?

Comment: Интересный подход..... Сейчас буду пробовать, но не уверен в успехе, так как пока не понял принципа.....  Как я понимаю, сумма должна быть в 'product-price', а вот как это на странице вывести? Так же, <output id="product-price"></output>    -  ничего не выводится...

А total_price - функция:

function total_price($cart)  
{
    $total_price = '0.00';
    
    global $link;
    
    ..........................
}

Comment: Ну неужели совсем без вариантов?????

Comment: Так, это вопрос решил - вышеподсказанным кодом цифры склеивались, и нашёл, как их перевести в цифры: "new Number (+rezultatRadio) + new Number (+totalPrice)".     А что мне нужно сделать (как я понимаю, нужно передать значение  'product-price'  из document.getElementById('product-price').innerHTML    в php-переменную, типа $product-price. А вот как это сделать - пока так и не понял...

Comment: Ну форма отправки должна быть, либо ajax прикрутить.

Comment: Имеется только вышеприведённый код, с input, который находится в форме. Как ajax прикрутить, есть примеры?